# FileSyncProvider does not recognize rename or move

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am building a sync app with a customprovider and a filesyncprovider. I based my provider on this example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/File-Sync-with-Simple-c497bf87

The problem that I see is that MOVES or RENAMES are not recognized by the Filesyncprovider as such. A MOVE is translated into a DELETE and CREATE. If I get an UPDATE request into the CustomSyncprovider, I can tell if it is a move or a rename and therefore react correctly.

Do I have to change something in my Customprovider to allow the Filesyncprovider to recognize the change correctly, or is the filesyncprovider not able to make this distinction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My custom sync provider is a FullEnumeration Sync Provider. Therefore the Filesyncprovider does not have the necessary information to recognize a move or rename. To implement that, my custom sync provider would have to be implemented as a KnowledgeSyncProvider.